# Is there an R function that counts the number of previous number of dates in a data frame and based on condition

Tags: r, dataframe, date, count

I want to count the number of previous absences each student has had before their most recent one and add those counts as a column in the data frame.

```
 Student ID       Absent Date       Subject        

    4567           08/30/2018          M
    4567           09/22/2019          M
    8345           09/01/2019          S
    8345           03/30/2019         PE         
    8345           07/18/2017          M
    5601           01/08/2019         SS
```

This is the desired output:

```
 Student ID       Absent Date       Subject       Previous Absence            

    4567           08/30/2018          M                 1
    4567           09/22/2019          M                 1
    8345           09/01/2019          S                 2
    8345           03/30/2019         PE                 2        
    8345           07/18/2017          M                 2
    5601           01/08/2019         SS                 0
```

I then want to calculate the number of previous absences each student had in math (M) and add those counts as a column in the data frame.

```
 Student ID       Absent Date       Subject       Previous Absence            

    4567           08/30/2018          M                 1
    4567           09/22/2019          M                 1
    8345           09/01/2019          S                 2
    8345           03/30/2019         PE                 2        
    8345           07/18/2017          M                 2
    5601           01/08/2019         SS                 0
```

The desired output:

```
 Student ID  Absent Date  Subject  Prior Absence  Prior M Absence              

    4567      08/30/2018       M           1            1
    4567      09/22/2019       M           1            1
    8345      09/01/2019       S           2            0
    8345      03/30/2019      PE           2            0        
    8345      07/18/2017       M           2            0
    5601      01/08/2019      SS           0            0
```

Thank you!

Comment: Could you clarify the "Prior M Absence" in your desired output? For Student ID 8345, the absence for math was in 2017, prior to the other absences, but the value for "Prior M Absence" is zero. Is that because this value reflects only Math classes absent in the past? Or was the date 7/18/2017 intended to be later than the other absent dates for this student?

Comment: @Ben Hi! "Prior M Absence" is the column for only previous math absences. So in this case it is 0 because student 8345 only had 1 absence in math meaning they never had any math absences before. If 2 out of the 3 absences student 8345 had was math, then the "Prior M Absence" output would be 1. I hope that makes sense:)

Comment: Why is the previous absent for ID 4567 in row 2 == 1 instead of 2? Isnt that his s2nd absence??

Comment: Hello @Onyambu ! it is 1 because there was only one previous absent. It is about how many times the student has previously been absent not the total absences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes that the data is already sorted by `Absent_Date` (at least within each `Student_ID`):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Student_ID) %>%
  mutate(
    n_prior_absence = n() - 1,
    n_prior_absence_math = sum(head(Subject, -1) == "M")
  )
# # A tibble: 6 × 5
# # Groups:   Student_ID [3]
#   Student_ID Absent_Date Subject n_prior_absence n_prior_absence_math
#        <int> <chr>       <chr>             <dbl>                <int>
# 1       4567 08/30/2018  M                     1                    1
# 2       4567 09/22/2019  M                     1                    1
# 3       8345 09/01/2019  S                     2                    0
# 4       8345 03/30/2019  PE                    2                    0
# 5       8345 07/18/2017  M                     2                    0
# 6       5601 01/08/2019  SS                    0                    0
```

---

Using this data:

```
df = read.table(text = 'Student_ID       Absent_Date       Subject        
4567           08/30/2018          M
4567           09/22/2019          M
8345           09/01/2019          S
8345           03/30/2019         PE         
8345           07/18/2017          M
5601           01/08/2019         SS', header = T)
```